# Building Blackberry 10 App bar file

Tags: code-signing, blackberry-10, publishing, blackberry-webworks, building

I found that no place over the internet listed all the steps to build a blackberry App (WebWorks) into a working bar file and how to install it to the device.

Comment: someone devoted my answer without providing a better one or reference  ?!

Comment: I think it is probably because your question isn't a question (A). Then also your question and answer have the same timestamp (B). I would probably downvote this too if I had a load of points and or cared enough.

Comment: I wasn't deceiving sir, I have used a kind of question that allows me to write the the question and answer 
http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: Honestly I was looking around the web and found nothing answering this and wanted to share the knowledge with other who are surviving looking for the same problem.

Comment: I was only addressing your confusion as to why somebody may down vote this question. Honestly regardless of whether you answer it I think the question itself could be more detailed. Furthermore what was wrong with http://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/cascades/getting_started/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Install BlackBerryGraphicalAid [Direct link](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Testing-and-Deployment/BlackBerry-Tablet-OS-Graphical-Aid/ta-p/1207067)

**1st time to sign the application**

- Ask for Keys and remember your PIN here: https://www.blackberry.com/SignedKeys/codesigning.html
- After receiving the keys by email from Blackberry, open the Blackberry Graphical Aid app
- Go to "configuration" tab
- Set the SDK path (skip Android if you don't need it)
- Create certificate (it's the author.p12)
- Will then ask you for the keys, and PIN (received via BB email) and a new password to set the certificate with, set them and now you are ready

**Signed this application before and need to resign it again (using diff PC)**

- you have to find the following files used for releasing the last released version

  - author.p12
  - barsigner.csk
  - barsigner.db
- Make sure these files are there in `C:\Users\youUserName\AppData\Local\Research In Motion`
- If you released an App World version using these keys then you have to keep it safe because if you used any other keys it will create a new app not a new version
- If you released a world version using these keys, that means you can't generate an author.p12 file again from the .csj(key files) files so you have to use the same one used before with the other 2 files barsigner.csk and barsigner.db

**To Publish to device for DEBUGGING purpose**

- Open the the blackberry Graphical Aid
- Go to "Debug Token" Tab
- Create a new Debug token using the same password created before(not the PIN)
- Install the debug token to the device
- To install anything to the device, you have to

  - connect the device using USB cable (I don't trust wifi connection in such stuff)
  - Device/Go to Privacy and security/ Development mode, enable development mode and set a password
  - When you connect your device using usb cable, the Blackberry connection app will ask you for the password to grant connection
- After installing the debug token

**Building the bar file to be installed (in both cases)**

- Zip your application files (from inside the root zip file will be created in the same folder of the index file)
- Go to Build webWorks tab
- Set the zip file location
- set a folder path for the resulting builds
- You must sing the application with the same password set before to publish to app world or debugging into a device

**Now if you are going publish it to the app world you have a bar file ready** 
else 
if you want to test on device go to "Install" tab 
- set the bar file generated from the last step (device version not simulator)
- set the device password and install
- Cheers